# A method to bound distances between sets

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms

I have two sets of points, $X$ and $Y$, which are finite and disjoint. I want to compute the distance between them defined by:
$$d(X,Y)=  \frac{\sum_{x \in X} \|x-Y\| + \sum_{y \in Y} \|y-X\|}{|x|+|y|} $$ where $\|x-Y\|$ represents the distance between the point $x$ in $X$ to its closest point in $Y$, and $|x|$, $|y|$ are the cardinalities of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Since both sets are large, the above formula is computationally expensive. How can I calculate it or bound it efficiently?

Comment: @MattF. Thanks for your help and the edit. I wrote **to bound** in the original question because it is hard to compute the distance exactly and an algorithm should be used to approximate _or bound_ the distance. Hope it is clear?

Comment: @MattF. As you know, the distance above is used as a metric to compare the similarity between two sets in neural networks. Unfortunately, I can't compute it exactly because of the amount of points since it needs to to search for the closest neighbor in Y for each point in X and to do the same again for each point in Y. Consequently, I am looking in literature for efficient methods to find the nearest neighbor in order to use them and to bound the distances above.

Comment: @MattF. So the most important and interesting is to find a known efficient method to find the nearest neighbor for all points in huge sets then I can work on the bound for the distance

Comment: If all you want is a bound from above, then let $p$ be the minimum of $X\cup Y$ (i.e. the first coordinate of $p$ is the minimum of all the first coordinates), and let $q$ be the maximum, and the distance between $p$ and $q$ provides an upper bound.

Answer (score 4):

Let $d(x,Y):=\min\{\|x-y\|\colon y\in Y\}$ and $d(y,X):=\min\{\|y-x\|\colon x\in X\}$. Then
$$d(X,Y)=(1-w)d_X(Y)+wd_Y(X),$$
where
$$w:=\frac{|Y|}{|X|+|Y|},$$
$|X|$ and $|Y|$ are the cardinalities of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and
$$d_X(Y):=\frac1{|X|}\sum_{x\in X}d(x,Y)\quad\text{and}\quad d_Y(X):=\frac1{|Y|}\sum_{y\in Y}d(y,X)$$
are the average distances from $X$ to $Y$ and from $Y$ to $X$, respectively.

Let $X_1$ and $Y_1$ be (say random) subsets of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, of large but not overly large sizes. Then, obviously, $d(x,Y)\le d(x,Y_1)$ for all $x$ and hence $d_X(Y)\le d_X(Y_1)$. Similarly, $d_Y(X)\le d_Y(X_1)$. So,
$$d(X,Y)\le(1-w)d_X(Y_1)+wd_Y(X_1).$$
One could also take some large enough (say random) subsets $X_2$ and $Y_2$ of $X$ and $Y$ such that $w_2:=\frac{|Y_2|}{|X_2|+|Y_2|}\approx w$ and thus get a presumably upper estimate
$$(1-w_2)d_{X_2}(Y_1)+w_2d_{Y_2}(X_1)$$
of $d(X,Y)$.

These methods should work well if $X$ and $Y$ are well enough separated from each other on an average and if $w$ is known or can be estimated well enough.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts. If I understand your work correctly, I think your method to compute the distance will also be computationally expensive as it needs additionally to calculate the distance between a huge number of points $x$ in $X$ to their nearest neighbors in $Y$. Apart from this, I don't understand why it is obvious that $d(x,Y) \leq d(x,Y_1)$? if the random set $Y_1$ contains the closest values of $Y$ to $X$ then $d(x,Y) \geq d(x,Y_1)$! Am I missing something?

Comment: @Flore : (i) "your method to compute the distance will also be computationally expensive as it needs additionally to calculate the distance between a huge number of points $x$ in $X$ to their nearest neighbors in $Y$. -- No, you only need to compute the nearest distance from the points in $X_2$ to $Y_1$ and from the points in $X_1$ to $Y_2$, and you can take these subsets of $X$ and $Y$ as moderate as you like (albeit paying the unavoidable price of lesser accuracy for the gain in the efficiency.)

Comment: @Flore : (ii) "why it is obvious that $d(x,Y)\le d(x,Y_1)$?" -- Because the minimum of any function over a subset $Y_1$ of $Y$ is always no less than the minimum of that function over the entire finite set $Y$. (iii) "if the random set $Y_1$ contains the closest values of $Y$ to $X$ then $d(x,Y)\ge d(x,Y_1)$!" -- If $Y_1$ contains the closest values of $Y$ to $x$ then $d(x,Y)=d(x,Y_1)$, so that $d(x,Y)\le d(x,Y_1)$ holds.